# How to get all initials of name stored in an array using 2 for loops?

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

The user inputs their full name into the console and gets stored in an array using getline(). The array that the name is stored in is of type "string"

The problem i am trying to solve is as follows:

> Include a for-loop that counts the number of names in the full name
>   and then uses that information in a second for loop that displays the
>   full name formally.

So if the user enters in 'Paul Matthew Jones', I want the console to display 'PM Jones'.

There are a few restrictions for the question. I can't use any functions. I must use only 2 loops and I must only use 1 array.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < myName.length(); i++)
{
    if (myName[i] == ' ')
    {
        nameLength = nameLength + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would figure out a way to do it w/o coding.  Once you have a way, then look into std::string member functions to implement what you have come up with.  As a hint, std::string has functions to search for characters that are contained in it.  Here's an excellent resource: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string

Comment: What is the data type of the array?  (Please edit your question with the answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Split the input to individual strings in first place (e.g. using `std::istringstream` and a `std::vector<std::string>` to collect them).
Then just collect all of the first characters and concatenate these, besides for the last string in the split up strings collection which should be appended in whole, and prefixed with a `' '` character.

Comment: Usually I would do that, but the task I have been given has stated that I cant do that and instead must think of a workaround.

Comment: @TomasHughes Huh, what please can't be used actually? Clarify such constraints clearly in your question please.

Comment: The question is as follows: 

Include a for-loop that counts the number of names in the full name and then uses that information in a second for loop that displays the full name formally.

So if the user enters in 'Paul Matthew Jones', I want the console to display 'PM Jones'.

Comment: @TomasHughes As mentioned, improve your question (Edit!!) with such additional requirements/information please.